# typescript overload type of node process.setuid() incompatible with union, issuing error TS2345

Tags: typescript, overload-resolution

I'm using typescript 2.2.1
to compile this node.js code that uses process.setuid():

```
// extracted from @types/node:
interface Process {
  setuid(id: number): void;
  setuid(id: string): void;
}
var process: Process
process.setuid(1)
process.setuid('a')
var either: string | number
process.setuid(either)      // issues error TS2345
```

but it issues this error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I believe the compiler should figure out that either will work.
It seems to me that the overloaded declarations for setuid() should together match the declared type of variable *either*

Is this a compiler bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1805

The main problem is that while your logic is valid for single parameters, it isn't valid for multiple parameters:

```
interface Process {
  setuid(id: number, id2: number): void;
  setuid(id: string, id2: string): void;
}
var process: Process;
var either1: string | number;
var either2: string | number;
process.setuid(either1, either2); // ?
```

While it's easy to reason about this in low-parameter-count situations, generalizing this to lots of parameters is very difficult. If you had something like this:

```
var a: string|number;
var b: string|boolean;
var c: boolean|number;

function fn(a: string|boolean, b: boolean, c: number|string);
function fn(a: boolean, b: string, c: number|string);
function fn(a: number|boolean, b: boolean, c: string|number);
function fn(a: string|boolean, b: string, c: boolean|number);
function fn() {}

fn(a, b, c); // Valid?
```

You can quickly see it's not easy, apart from full expansion of *all possible inputs* (which is combinatorially explosive), to determine whether something would be a valid call or not. Since union types in TypeScript can easily have dozens of members (e.g. enums), it's not practical for the compiler do eagerly do this expansion.

In general if a function overload *can* be written with union types, it should:

```
interface Process {
  // Better.
  setuid(id: number | string): void;
}
```

There is a TSLint rule which will enforce this: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/unified-signatures/

Comment: If I understand correctly, the case of a single parameter is a special case of a more general pattern that is not supported because of the complexity in the compiler.  So, perhaps my best option is to run TSLint on the node.js typings, using the TSLint rule you mentioned, and create a PR that includes repairs. And I should probably review typings for all related functions, as well as those that have similar signatures in the node.js documentation.